# Favorite way to synchronize sqlite3 db on iPhone over HTTP

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, http, sqlite

I currently have an sqlite3 database in my iPhone application. The database has grown to 10MB+ on its own with all of the data I've thrown at it so far. Some of the data I'd rather not have part of the App Bundle as well.

If I provide just the schema, what's your favorite way of syncing all of the tables over HTTP?

Comment: Please elaborate: do you want to take some of the initial data from the app bundle, and some of it from a server somewhere; and to allow the app to update that data, but also to allow the server to update it? And will these updates be happening to the same tables?

Answer (score 0):

use a tag filed to identify whether the record was synced  . both iphone side database and server side.